# Connecting MSSQL Server with Codeigniter

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

Iam running a codeigniter application which is hosted in IIS 7.Now I need it to use MSSQL server as DBMS.But I found some difficulties with connecting to MSSQL.can anybody please provide me with a good guide about this process.
thank you..

Answer (score 1):

In the database configuration file, specify the database driver.
The config file is located at application/config/database.php

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mssql";
```

Reference : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: Is it enough?? what about ms sql drivers?? I have notiecd that there is a driver called Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server on the internet.should i use that?? and i dont see any mssql drivers which are not enable in the php_ini.. below link is what iam reffering for..http://futbolsalas15.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/7-steps-to-make-sql-server-and-codeigniter-works/

Comment: If so, it is needed I didn't tested it, In CI configuration, only this is needed. Thank you.